# If a card with a pull has an effect that boots the character, do they boot only if successful?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded

Consider a card like [Soothe](http://dtdb.co/find/?q=soothe) from *Faith & Fear*:

> **Noon Miracle 10, Boot:** Boot this Blessed to unboot another dude at this or an adjacent location.

This card has a pull and an effect that includes booting the character. Am I right in saying that the character only gets booted if the pull is successful, and the character is not booted if it is not? (The Miracle would of course be booted either way, since that is the cost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct that the character is only booted if the pull is successful.

Per the rulebook page 29, under 'Spells':

> If the skill check equals or exceeds the spell's difficulty, the spell succeeds and you use that ability. Otherwise, the spell fails and **nothing happens**.